# angularjs/bootstrap: apply complicated style on the fly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to define a colour scheme for my site and I want to see the effect of some complicated style on some buttons (for example). I have the following HTML:

```
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                <p>Primary</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                <p>%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                <p>Gradient</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                <p>%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <p>Hover/Active</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="color" data-ng-model="colors[0]" data-ng-change="colChange()" /> <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" data-ng-model="colors[0]" data-ng-change="colChange()" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" data-ng-model="colors[1]" data-ng-change="colChange()">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="color" data-ng-model="colors[2]" /> <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" data-ng-model="colors[2]" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" data-ng-model="colors[3]" data-ng-change="colChange()">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="color" data-ng-model="colors[4]" /> <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" data-ng-model="colors[4]" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="color" data-ng-model="colors[5]" /> <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" data-ng-model="colors[5]" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>.btn-custom {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color: #{{colors[2].substring(1)}};
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[0].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[2].substring(1)}});
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#{{colors[0].substring(1)}}), to(#{{colors[2].substring(1)}}));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[0].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[2].substring(1)}});
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[0].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[2].substring(1)}});
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #{{colors[0].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[2].substring(1)}});
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff{{colors[0].substring(1)}}', endColorstr='#ff{{colors[2].substring(1)}}', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #{{colors[2].substring(1)}} #{{colors[2].substring(1)}} #{{colors[0].substring(1)}};
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color: #{{colors[2].substring(1)}};
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled= false);
}

.btn-custom:active, .btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom:hover {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[4].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[5].substring(1)}});
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#{{colors[4].substring(1)}}), to(#{{colors[5].substring(1)}}));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[4].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[5].substring(1)}});
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #{{colors[4].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[5].substring(1)}});
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #{{colors[4].substring(1)}}, #{{colors[5].substring(1)}});
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff{{colors[4].substring(1)}}', endColorstr='#ff{{colors[5].substring(1)}}', GradientType=0);
    *background-color: #{{colors[5].substring(1)}};
}

.btn-custom:active, .btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

.btn-custom.disabled, .btn-custom[disabled] {
    color: #777;
}</pre>
```

This generates the CSS which I can add to my CSS file, refresh the page and see the effect.

For info, my controller has this (where colorLuminance() is just a function that increases the provided colours luminance by a bit):

```
// Primary, luminance%, grad end, luminance%, hover start, hover end 
$scope.colors=['#3b0084', 160, '', 130, '', ''];
$scope.colChange = function() {
    console.log("colChange()");
    $scope.colors[2] = colorLuminance( $scope.colors[0], ($scope.colors[1]/100)-1 );
    $scope.colors[4] = colorLuminance( $scope.colors[0], ($scope.colors[3]/100)-1 );
    $scope.colors[5] = colorLuminance( $scope.colors[4], ($scope.colors[1]/100)-1 );
};
$scope.colChange();
```

Is there a way I can apply the generated style, to a button on the homepage?

I did find another question that pointed me at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4NlIfgfXIiNHWu5oTzS?p=preview

But I couldn't see how to make it update and provide the more complex conditional stuff for hover etc.

I did think about a iframe injecting a raw page generated with the style, but I['m not sure how to do that.

Any help much appreciated.

### EDIT

I tried to implement the html injection, however when I pull the text out of the PRE element via jQuery:

```
style = $('pre.styleInsert').text();
```

I get the text with the angular code in :(

Comment: you want to set some styles and refresh the page and after that apply that styles... that's what you want?

Comment: Yep, but without the refresh of the page bit :)